# Upgarding CefSharp from 49.0.1 to 57.0.0

Tags: c#, cefsharp, .net-4.6

The chromium browser was working perfectly in CefSharp 49.0.1 and .NET 4.5. As we moved to .NET 4.6.1 I decided to upgrade CefSharp. I tried v55.0.0 and v57.0.0. But nothing is shown in the browser... What is missing here?

```
<Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="{Binding Url}" />
</Grid>
```

I set url to "www.google.com" in the ViewModel but the browser is blank.
Also when I close the window I see these lines in the output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.dll
```

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1956

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solutions to the blank browser problem in this link.